# How to make a table shows the change time by time in r

Tags: r, time-series

My data looks like

```
ID  Joint_time  leave_time  group
1   201501      201603      2
2   201508      201601      2
3   201503      201601      2
4   201512      201601      3
5   201511      201602      2
6   201503      .           1
7   201503      .           1
8   201506      201602      3
9   201507      .           1
10  201503      .           1
11  201601      201602      2
12  201601      .           1
13  201601      201603      2
14  201601      201602      3
15  201601      201602      3
16  201602      .           1
17  201602      .           1
18  201602      201603      3
19  201602      .           1
20  201602      .           1
21  201602      .           1
22  201603      .           1
23  201603      .           1
24  201603      .           1
25  201603      .           1
26  201603      .           1
27  201603      .           1
28  201603      .           1
```

I want to know the change and total customer number in the end of each month. I want to demonstrate the leaving and joining customer number. I only know to use table(). But this code does not seem to deal with this kind of complex table.
My data is as following

```
 ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28)
Joint_time<-c("201501","201508","201503","201512","201511","201503","201503","201506","201507","201503","201601","201601","201601","201601","201601","201602","201602","201602","201602","201602","201602","201603","201603","201603","201603","201603","201603","201603")
leave_time<-c("201603","201601","201601","201601","201602",".",".","201602",".",".","201602",".","201603","201602","201602",".",".","201603",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".")
group<-c(2,2,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
question_table<-data.frame(ID,Joint_time,leave_time,group)
```

I would like to build a table as following

```
                                               201601   201602  201603
Total number in month beginning                    10       12      13
Joint this month                                    5        6       7
Group 2 who joint during 2015 leave this month      2        1       1
Group 2 who joint during 2016 leave this month      0        1       1
Group 3 who joint during 2015 leave this month      1        1       0
Group 3 who joint during 2016 leave this month      0        2       1
Total number in month end                          12       13      17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to help with each part of the needed output as I don't believe it is a good idea to put all that data in that format in a single data frame. If you definitely require it in that format, I may edit the answer.

To compute the number of people from different groups and join years leaving, you can using a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
question_table %>%
  filter(leave_time != '.') %>%
  mutate(Joint_year = substr(Joint_time, 1, 4)) %>%
  group_by(group, leave_time, Joint_year) %>%
  summarise(left = n()) %>%
  spread(leave_time, left, fill = 0)
```

Returned output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
Groups: group [2]

  group Joint_year 201601 201602 201603
  (dbl)      (chr)  (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)
1     2       2015      2      1      1
2     2       2016      0      1      1
3     3       2015      1      1      0
4     3       2016      0      2      1
```

To summarise, how many people joined in each of those 2016 months, you can do something like this:

```
question_table %>%
  filter(Joint_time %in% c('201601', '201602', '201603')) %>%
  group_by(Joint_time) %>%
  summarise(joined = n()) %>%
  spread(Joint_time, joined, fill = 0)

Source: local data frame [1 x 3]

  201601 201602 201603
   (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)
1      5      6      7
```

In this case, you are better off avoiding the `spread` at the end and retaining the data in long format. But, that is up to you.

As for the last part of getting total customers at the beginning of each period, you can do something like this:

```
question_table$Joint_time <- as.character(question_table$Joint_time)
question_table$leave_time <- as.character(question_table$leave_time)

df <- data.frame(numberBeginning = sapply(sort(unique(question_table$leave_time[question_table$leave_time != '.'])), function(x) nrow(filter(question_table, Joint_time < x, leave_time == '.' | leave_time >= x))))
```

If you want to get the last one in wide format, it needs some more work:

```
df$period <- row.names(df)
row.names(df) <- NULL
df <- spread(df, period, numberBeginning)

  201601 201602 201603
1     10     12     13
```

You can modify the above code slightly to get the last bit of information on numbers ending as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(numberEnding = sapply(sort(unique(question_table$leave_time[question_table$leave_time != '.'])), function(x) nrow(filter(question_table, Joint_time <= x, leave_time == '.' | leave_time > x))))
df$period <- row.names(df)
row.names(df) <- NULL
df <- spread(df, period, numberEnding)
df
  201601 201602 201603
1     12     13     17
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I vertical merge all four "df"s, which you made, into a single table?

Comment: Sure, using `rbind` can be helpful. Just that I don't like to keep disparate data in same data frame. You may need to save into four names instead of `df` as I used above. And, perhaps you can up vote and accept the answer if it meets your needs.

Comment: After I run the code of 'df<-data.frame()' ,it shows "‘>=’ not meaningful for factors". How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry....I had to convert it to character column. Forgot to add that code. But, best place to do it is with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in reading the data.

Comment: Edited answer to include those two lines as well.